# Show that $ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} f(x+y)x^m y^n\ dx\ dy= c_{mn}\int_0^1 f(t) t^{m+n+1} dt $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The exercise is to show that for a function $f$ defined in $\mathbb{R^2}$ the following equality holds:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} f(x+y)x^m y^n\  dx\ dy= c_{mn}\int_0^1 f(t) t^{m+n+1} dt $$ Where $$c_{mn} = \int_0^1 (1-t)^m t^n dt$$

My attempt:

Let $x= u-v$ and $y=v$. The determinant of the jacobian of $g:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ (such that$\ (u,v)\rightarrow (u-v,v))$  is $1$, and so, taking the left hand side of the first equality, we get:
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} f(x+y)x^m y^n\  dx\ dy= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(u-v+v) (u-v)^m  \ v^n \ dv\ du $$ $$= \int_0^1 f(u) \left(\int_0^1  (u-v)^m  \ v^n \ dv\right) \ du$$ and now I'm stuck.
I can't seem to find a way to relate the integral
$$\int_0^1  (u-v)^m  \ v^n \ dv$$ with $c_{mn}$. Substitution and integration by parts didn't help.

Comment: $$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^u \cdots \, dv \right) \,du
$$
Here you need $\displaystyle \int_0^u\cdots\,dv$ rather than $\displaystyle \int_0^1\cdots\,dv.\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Try to let $x = u(1-v)$ and $y = ab$ and use exactly the same method.